# How can I call my class python file in my main python file?

Tags: python

I am having a problem calling my class and function to my main code. I created a class and do the method in it and just call it in my main code.

This is my class:

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet
class syn:
    def synon():
        f = open('filename', "r")
        first = f.readline()
        print("1. ", first)
        input_ans = input('Answer: ')
        synonyms = []
        for syn in wordnet.synsets(first):
            for l in syn.lemmas():
                synonyms.append(l.name())
        if input_ans == first:
            score += 0
            print("Wrong")
        elif input_ans in set(synonyms):
            print("Correct")
            score += 1
        else:
            score += 0
            print("Wrong")
```

This is my main code:

```
import os
from synonyms import syn
from nltk.corpus import wordnet

a = syn()
a.synon()
```

It does not print anything.

Comment: Python is not Java. You didn't have to wrap functions in classes. They work happily on their own.

Comment: you have typo `a.syno()` -> `a.synon()`

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you are missing the `self` argument. See [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709821/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-word-self) for more logic behind why it's needed. If you're going to wrap the function in a class, you might find `__init__` and other "dunder" methods interesting.

Here is a toy example that will do what you want:

```py
class syn:
    def member_function(self):
        print("hello from syn")
        
a = syn()
a.member_function()
```

Comment: There are no class attributes in this case. Method should have `@staticmethod` decorator.

Comment: It worked now. I just have a typo. What does it mean when I have no attribute in function? I am having an error from part of score.